If carbon sequestration is the way forward, will this not reduce the oxygen content of the earth's atmosphere as it will bypass photosynthesis?
The issue I raise in the title is my main concern relating to the sequestration of CO2, which, if we continue to use synthetic carbon based, fuels, will over time lead to a reduction in the oxygen content within our atmosphere.

There is 20% oxygen, and 0.04% of CO2 in the atmosphere. Which sources do you think synthetic fuels will derive the carbon from?

What is "synthetic carbon based fuel" are you talking about petroleum derived fuels or biofuels.

A LOT of CCS seems unlikely - has to become the biggest global industry(?), all subsidized. One estimate is RCP8.5 would lower O2 from 20.946% to 20.825% by 2100. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S209592731830375X -  but depends on what we do about energy and emissions and other factors as well as CCS, ie it is complex. RCP8.5 was always "worst case", now considered unlikely, so less than that. I think global warming impacts and concern around CO2 (without CCS) will totally overwhelm concerns for O2 levels.
